Example of an Accidental Cycle in a Hyperbolic Polygon
I am trying to understand the concept of accidental cycles of a hyperbolic polygon through a numerical example.
Definition: Accidental cycle
If an elliptic cycle transformation is the identity then we call the elliptic cycle an accidental cycle.
Question
In Walkden's note, there is an example of side-pairing transformations as follows. And I believe $\gamma_{s_3}(z)$ is an example of the accidental cycle.
An Example from Walkden's note (P.84)
Let $ \Gamma = \{ \gamma_n \mid \gamma_n(z) = z + n, n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $ be the Fuchsian group of integer translations. We have seen that if $ p = i $ then $ D(p) = \{ z \in \mathbb{H} \mid -1/2 < \text{Re}(z) < 1/2 \} $ is a Dirichlet polygon for $ \Gamma $.
Then, I set the vertices and sides ($v_3$ is the ideal vertex.) as follows;

Then, I have worked out the cycles as follows;

$(v_1, s_2) \overset{\gamma_1: z \mapsto z+1}{\rightarrow} (v_2, s_3) \overset{\gamma_2: z \mapsto z-1}{\rightarrow} (v_1, s_2)$

$(v_3, s_1) \overset{\gamma_3: z \mapsto z}{\rightarrow} (v_3, s_1)$

So in this case, the second cycle is accidental?

Can you provide any other example of accidental cycles?


Reference

Walkden's note: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Charles.Walkden/hyperbolic-geometry/hyperbolic_geometry.pdf


In your example, $\gamma_2 = \gamma_1^{-1}$. For any Fuchsian group $\Gamma$, any fundamental polygon of $\Gamma$, and any side-pairing transformation $\gamma \in \Gamma$ of that polygon, $\gamma^{-1}$ is also a side-pairing transformation. So every single point on the boundary of the polygon produces an example of an "accidental cycle". This is a hint that as currently formulated this concept is not useful.

Got it! Thank you so much for your prompt response!
